# freeTDS on Linux and Azure database, login issue

Tags: linux, t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database, freetds

I try to connect to Azure database like:

```
 tsql -H XXXXXX.database.windows.net -p 1433 -U mycorrectusername
```

but I got message

```
Msg 20004, Level 9, State 0, Server OpenClient, Line 0
Read from SQL server failed.
Msg 20014, Level 9, State 0, Server OpenClient, Line 0
Login incorrect.
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

It is possible that I cant login because I have to choose database first. I have to, when I log in via website.

When I try to choose database like:

```
tsql -H XXXXXXXXX.database.windows.net -p 1433 -U username -D databasename
```

but I get message:

```
tsql: illegal option -- D
```

Here is tsql configuration:

```
[~]$ tsql -C
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script):
                       Version: freetds v0.64
MS db-lib source compatibility: yes
   Sybase binary compatibility: unknown
                 Thread safety: yes
                 iconv library: yes
                   TDS version: 5.0
                         iODBC: no
                      unixodbc: no
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to connect with Azure database with FreeTDS v0.64. The solution is to compile the newest freetds version, currently 0.91. The sources are avalible here:

```
https://gitorious.org/freetds/freetds/source/a6898bdd6fa115447366ddbc76830e6826ea5d21:
```

and compile it with ms dblib source compatibility option (and tls or openssl for the encrypted connection).