# MS SQL connection with FreeTDS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, azure, freetds

I am trying to connecting to MS SQL database on Azure with the help of this [tutorial](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Platform-Installation---Ubuntu) . After initial configurations when i try to connect to server with following command (with my own credentials )

```
sqsh -S developer -U database_username -P database_password
```

i got following error

```
Open Client Message
Layer 0, Origin 0, Severity 78, Number 49
Unexpected EOF from the server
Open Client Message
Layer 0, Origin 0, Severity 78, Number 34
Adaptive Server connection failed
```

I find following error from freetds logs

```
login.c:1057:detected flag 3
login.c:1068:server required encryption but support is not compiled in
login.c:466:login packet rejected
util.c:156:Changed query state from IDLE to DEAD
util.c:331:tdserror(0x98098f0, 0x9809ab0, 20002, 0)
util.c:361:tdserror: client library returned TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
util.c:384:tdserror: returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
mem.c:615:tds_free_all_results()
```

my credentials are right don't know why its not working. I have tried couple of other tutorials but every one resulting in failure
your help will be  much appreciated
thanks

Comment: Assuming you are talking about Azure SQL Database (PaaS) and not SQL Server running on an Azure virtual machine this is most likely your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845687/freetds-on-linux-and-azure-database-login-issue